# Problema creating standalone client with Tkinter and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a problem creating an executable of my Tkinter application with pyinstaller.
Initially, it makes sense to warn you that in the past I've used exactly the command line given below, and it was always possible to build the executable without any errors! However, I had an issue with my desktop and continued working on another device (Windows laptop).

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=ai_icon.ico --add-data="C:\Users\paulo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos\NFBK\nfbk-system\Beta\NFBK System\V_0_0_1\EDF_Files\*;." --add-data="C:\Users\paulo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos\NFBK\nfbk-system\Beta\NFBK System\V_0_0_1\ai.png;img" --add-data="C:\Users\paulo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos\NFBK\nfbk-system\Beta\NFBK System\V_0_0_1\circle.png;img" --add-data="C:\Users\paulo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos\NFBK\nfbk-system\Beta\NFBK System\V_0_0_1\ai_icon.ico;img" --add-data="C:\Users\paulo\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos\NFBK\nfbk-system\Beta\NFBK System\V_0_0_1\standard_1020.elc;img" --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._weight_vector" ClassGUI.py SignalProcessing.py GraphicalClass.py
```

After the end of the process, the executable is created, however, the following error is presented. I can't understand why a file is missing, if I have the same project files that were on my desktop (since I recovered the project via git).

[image: ERROR]

My initial hypothesis is that I may have installed versions of the libraries that may conflict with something, in this way, follow the information obtained via pip list, and the Python Version is 3.10.6

[image]
[image]